# How to stub a javascript library like html2canvas

Tags: ember.js, sinon, html2canvas

I have to test an ember app that uses html2canvas library, but the test is failing and I believe its because of the promise. I have already wrapped the asynchronous part like this:

```
/**
 * This method render DOM object (webpage) and generated canvas object using html2canvas library.
 * After getting canvas object it set image property.
 *
 * @method 'captureScreen'
 * @param {DOM}
 * @return {Ember.RSVP.Promise}
 */
captureScreen: function (dom) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve) => {
        html2canvas(dom).then((canvas) => {
            resolve(canvas);
        });
    });
}
```

So now I am trying to stub the html2canvas lib itself like this:

```
stubHtml2Canvas = function () {
    _stubHtml2Canvas = sinon.stub(html2canvas).returns(new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve) {
        resolve(document.createElement("CANVAS"));
    }));
}
```

but this throws out following err:

**beforeEach failed on should show overlay when clicking on the insight capture button: Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function**

I had also tried

```
sinon.createStubInstance(html2canvas).returns(new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve) {
        resolve(document.createElement("CANVAS"));
    }));
```

But that didn't work either.

I can stub out the "captureScreen" method itself and get things working but I rather learn the alternative option too.

Comment: Can't help you out im affraind, but maybe you can help me out getting html2canvas working with Ember, with an example or something ?

Comment: I would be more than happy to help you out but I think it will serve the community better if you ask this as separate question, send me a link to that question and I will provide the solution that I used - but I am pretty sure someone else will beat me to it :)

Comment: Here is the jsbin anyways 
: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sedejazeje/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You are my hero, you saved me a lot of time!!
Now i have to found out how i can image's on the canvas to :p